# How to use end="" parameter in f-string print format?

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, printing

```
afs="Hello, World! KD herfe"
print("[",end="")
for ad in afs:
    if ad!=" ":
        # print(ad,end="")
        print(f"{ad}")
    else:
        print("",end="")
print("]")
```

Here I wanted to print afs using f-string in this form

```
[Hello,World!KDherfe]
```

Output is right if commented f-string version but I wanted to know how use end parameter in f-string.

[image]

Comment: The print statement will always print on a new line unless you specify `end=""` just like you did in the second line of the snippet. Something like this: `print(f"{ad}", end="")`

Comment: There's no difference between `print(ad)` and `print(f"{ad}")`, and you use `end=""` the same with both.

Comment: Or in other words, `print` doesn't care or know whether you used an f-string, a variable, or a regular string as the first argument. If you pass in an `end=` keyword argument at the end, it will control how the line ending is handled, in all of these cases.

Comment: you get the same result if you remove `else: print("",end="")` because this part adds nothing to displayed text

Comment: you may say that Python thread it as `text = f"{ad}"` `print(text)` and `text = ad` `print(text)` - so `print()` doesn't care if you use `f-string` or directly `ad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
afs="Hello, World! KD herfe"
print("[", end="")
for ad in afs:
    if ad != " ":
        print(f"{ad}", end="")

print("]")
```

You can just use `end=""` normally after a comma in any print statement. It is a keyword argument (often called a `kwarg`). It does not matter if your first argument is a string (ie: `"["`), a variable (ie: `ad`) or an f-string (ie: `f"{ad}"`).

For what it's worth you can achieve the same thing by calling `replace()` on an f-string in a single `print` statement.

```
afs="Hello, World! KD herfe"
print(f"[{afs}]".replace(" ",""))
```